# PHP / MySQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying just to do a simple "take information from table and echo it" but just can't work it out. Has anyone got any pointers?

I am using the below code:

```
$servername = IS CORRECT;

$username = IS CORRECT;

$password = IS CORRECT;

$dbname = IS CORRECT;


// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
echo "Connected successfully";


$sql = "SELECT count FROM Ticket WHERE id = 1";

$Kevin = mysqli_query($sql);

echo $Kevin;

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You never select a database. You also did not retrieve your rows properly if you had anyway.

Comment: `$Kevin` is a resource for the result set, not displayable without fetching each result in turn... see the [examples in the PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for how to use it

Comment: echo $Kevin also does not get your information from the database. You also have to select it. Bytheway: How about using PDO?

Comment: Are you counting the records?

Comment: `mysqli_query` requires 2 parameters.

Comment: "Count" is a name of one of the columns in the database. its basically counting an input (managed separately) and outputting the column does that column need renaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quit sure, if you want to count the number of tickets, or you have a column with the name count?

If you are counting this is what you should do

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql   = "SELECT count(*) as ticketsCount FROM Ticket WHERE id = 1";
$kevin = $conn->query($sql);

if ($kevin->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $kevin->fetch_assoc();

    echo $row['ticketsCount'];

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Or If it happens that you have a column named 'count'  this is what you should do

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT `count` FROM Ticket WHERE id = 1";
$Kevin = $conn->query($sql);

if ($Kevin->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $Kevin->fetch_assoc()) {

       echo $row['count'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I do have have a column named 'count' and thanks! you got it!

Comment: @MichaelE great that you've managed to get it to work.. once you are comfortable with mysqli then try mysqli with prepared statements or pdo prepared statements

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that you are not using any DB, `Count` is a keyword in `SQL`. If indeed you have a field count, try:

```
$sql = "SELECT `count` FROM Ticket WHERE id = 1"
```

Else if you want to use Count() function, try:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Ticket WHERE id = 1"
```

Comment: It should be backticks not single quotes to escape the field name

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to choose which database to choose. You declare it, but you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

On **4th paramenter** of mysqli you should **input your database name**, as you can see in [PHP mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.construct.php).

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Also, you should check @apomene comment, where he says you should wrap your column name with ´count´.

You also need to fetch before echoing. You can check [Fetch documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).